How to deactivate a button after clicking? (Flet)
How can I make the button deactivate with one click?
`
import flet as ft
from flet import ElevatedButton, ButtonStyle, RoundedRectangleBorder

def main(page: ft.page):
    page.title = "Test"
    page.window_width = 400.00
    page.window_height = 500.00

    def change_color(color):
        page.add(ft.Row([ft.Text('Go')], alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER))

        btn_green.disabled = True

    btn_green = ElevatedButton(text='Click me', bgcolor=ft.colors.GREEN, color='white',
                       width=110,
                       height=30,
                       style=ButtonStyle(shape=RoundedRectangleBorder(radius=10)),
                       on_click=change_color)


    page.add(ft.Row([
        btn_green
    ], alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER))

ft.app(target=main)`

`
Now deactivation after two clicks
I can’t understand why it works with two clicks

Added
page.update() 

and everything works fine.
